# How to redirect to another page with chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'am trying to create a chrome plugin and I need to redirect the currently url to my website but the window.location is not working.

```
function redirect() {
chrome.tabs.query(
    {
        currentWindow: true,
        active: true 
    },
    function (foundTabs) {
        if (foundTabs.length > 0) {
            var url = foundTabs[0].url; 
            window.location = "http://www.example.com/x.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url);
        }
    }
);
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  redirect();
});
```

Does anyone knows how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running the extension at `document-start` or at `document-end`?

Comment: You are confusing background- and content-script functionality. Where is the above code run from ? Also, please, post your manifest.